# Incorrect filling of Python docstrings in pep257 mode

Tags: python, fill-paragraph

I have `python-fill-docstring-style` set to `pep-257` (default) and I'm trying to fill docstring paragraphs. However, python mode does not count `"""` towards the number of characters, nor does it consider indentation, resulting in:

```
def function(self):
    """a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
    a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
    a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
    """
```

and

```
class A:
    def function(self):
        """a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
        a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
        a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
        """
```

Note the incorrectly filled first row. How can I fix this?

Comment: [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#multi-line-docstrings) specifies that the first line of a multi-line docstring should be a one-line summary, followed by a blank line, then a full description. So the first line shouldn't be wrapping, anyway.

Comment: That is probably a reason nobody cared. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: [Bug#21254](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21254) might be related